# Can't launch Startup Security Utility

Tags: imac-pro

Today was one of those days. Long story short, an old LaCie drive failed spectacularly and I meant to replace it with two, LaCie d2 6TB Thunderbolt 3 drives running RAID 1. I use SoftRaid. I have an iMac Pro.

1. SoftRaid recognized the drives, but wouldn't use them to build a RAID 1 volume because of some voodoo LaCie does that makes it look externally like there's only a few MB available.
2. The only thing SoftRaid would allow me to do is delete the 6TB volume on each drive. Which I did. Now nothing recognizes the drives at all.
3. Softraid started doing its "reinstall driver and restart" endless loop. No problem, I thought. Just disconnect all of my SoftRaid volumes, boot into Recovery Mode and use Startup Security Utility to turn off Secure Boot.
4. Tried to run Startup Security Utility. Tells me that there are no administrator accounts (?) so it won't let me load it.
5. Deleted .AppleSetupDone and reinstalled High Sierra, went through setup and created a new admin account, following Googled instructions. No difference.
6. Tried booting into Single User Mode to see if I could terminal-foo my way out of it. Hangs after an "AdjustBusy timeout in 40000ms!" so I could never get to a command prompt.

So at the moment, I'm at a loss. I can't load Startup Security Utility, and I think my road to recovery begins there. Really want to avoid the whole 2-day format/restore cycle. Any ideas?

Comment: Just double-checking - I know you've just added the bounty, but since it's been a couple of weeks since you originally posted this question, has anything changed? Or is there anything new to add? Also, am I correct in assuming you can log in fine and use your iMac Pro normally (and have no problems using the Admin account in typical ways within macOS)? And, considering some of the intermittent issues some users are having with macOS High SIerra 10.13.4, can you confirm if that's the version you're using?

Comment: Nothing has changed. I use my iMac Pro daily without any issues. The only reason this came up was that Softraid started acting up on me and I was trying to follow their instructions for disabling Secure Boot settings, which led to this avalanche of problems. (Can't startup in single user mode, can't run the Startup Security Utility, etc.) My latest tack is to try to mount the recovery volume and add an admin account to it, but my understanding of APFS volume handling is limited. Still trying.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've had a chance to try anything in my answer yet, but I wanted to ask another question as I realised I had made an assumption about your post. Can you clarify whether you had ever previously used Startup Security Utility **prior** to this issue? I assumed you had and that not being able to now was *new* behaviour potentially related to this issue, but upon re-reading your question I realise I was just making assumptions!

Comment: Well, I've been offline for a few days as I went through the process of erasing the internal SSD and reinstalling High Sierra. What a pain! I had to connect to a second Mac using Apple Configurator 2, format the drive, and endure almost 24 hours of Internet Recovery. All because I couldn't do my usual sequence in the past of booting off a thumb drive or external HD. I can report that I can get access to Startup Security Utility and turn Secure Boot off so I don't have to endure this in the future, but booting in single user mode fails with the same AdjustBusy timeout error.

Comment: I understand Apple's kneejerk reaction to Spectre/Meltdown and their desire to be seen as a "secure" platform, but truth be told, all it does is make things harder for actual owners to service their devices. You can still Target Disk your way to the internal SSD. I'll just keep Secure Boot turned off and my Mac under (physical) lock and key. I'd still like to figure out the single user mode issue, though. Google provides no love.

Comment: Yes, I understand this can be frustrating. One of the first things I did with my iMac Pro was change the settings in the Startup Security Utility to ensure I could boot from external drives if/when necessary. As for booting into Single User Mode, have you had a chance to try any of the troubleshooting steps in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, troubleshooting is a process of elimination and often requires patience.

The first thing I would do is remove any non-Apple hardware (if connected) and try again. If this makes no difference, then I would proceed with resetting the NVRAM of your iMac Pro.

**How to reset NVRAM on an iMac Pro**

Follow these steps:

1. If you have a firmware password, first disable it before proceeding
2. Fully shut down your iMac Pro
3. Switch on your iMac Pro
4. Immediately press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys.
5. Keep the keys down until **after** the Apple logo appears and disappears for the **second time**.
6. Allow your iMac Pro to finish booting up. (**NOTE:** Upon reboot you *may* need to reconfigure some of your System Preferences (e.g. sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, time zone, etc).
7. Now reboot your iMac Pro and use the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys to boot into Recovery Mode and see if you can get the Startup Security Utility to work.

If this works, all good! If not, let's investigate Single User Mode again.

**Single User Mode**

Since your iMac Pro itself seems to be running fine in normal usage, another thing to investigate is the issue you're having booting into Single User Mode. Some additional things to check:

1. If you have a firmware password you must disable it first. You can't boot into Single User Mode (or Verbose Mode either) with a firmware password enabled. So, if you have one, disable it and try again (I suspect if you had one it'd be disabled anyway if you followed my steps for resetting the NVRAM, but just wanted to be thorough and mention it again).
2. If you didn't have a firmware password, or if disabling it doesn't work, then try booting into Verbose Mode instead. The process is the same, except that you're holding down the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> keys instead. Verbose Mode is actually a normal boot, except that you're seeing a description on screen as to what's actually happening during the boot process. You'll know you're in verbose mode when you start seeing white text on a black screen.

If you can boot into Single User Mode, great! If not, let us know if you see anything of interest when booting via Verbose Mode.

**About the AdjustBusy timeout error**

The AdjustBusy timeout error while booting into Single User Mode is interesting and one of the reasons I asked at the outset for you to remove any non-Apple hardware. Typically this relates to an IOService (don't worry about the technicalities - it's basically just referring to input/output devices and drivers).

Anyway, if you're still seeing this error, I would do the following:

1. Boot your iMac Pro normally
2. Launch the Terminal app (found within your Applications > Utilites folder)
3. Type (or copy and paste) the following command:

`kextstat | grep -v com.apple`

4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Within moments Terminal will list all 3rd party kernel extensions (Note: you may need to stretch the Terminal window so it's easier to read).

The above process is used to identify any 3rd party extensions you have installed. While this is a list of **all** 3rd party kernel extensions, I'm interested specifically in anything you don't remember installing, or something that belongs to software you no longer use. Also look out for anything that could be related in some way to LaCie hardware (either current or old) or to SoftRaid.

Let me know if there's anything of interest.